# How to disconnect solar charge controller from battery when AC charger is plugged?

Tags: battery-charging, switching

I am building a portable solar generator that I want to be able to switch between 2 charging sources. When the AC charger is plugged, it should disconnect the solar panels.

Availability of components and cost is an issue in my country so i am wondering whats the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Simple solution a blocking diode from the Solar Panel. This will be in series and reverse biased if the charger is greater than the PV

Comment: My experience is that, with properly designed and reasonably modern AC/Solar chargers, it is unnecessary to disconnect a solar charger when connecting an AC charger. The solar charger will simply stop contributing when it detects a sufficiently high battery voltage. You could always use a diode for protection but this will lower the voltage going into the battery, thus preventing it from charging completely.

Comment: @StarCat wouldn't it be a problem with my ac charger if the solar charger has higher volts?